# What does the error VgTs_WaitSys mean in Valgrind?

Tags: c, multithreading, valgrind

I have a server written in C that spawns a new thread whenever a new client connects. In order to test my server I have written a script that emulates 500 clients. The server handles the first couple of hundred clients and towards the end I get the following error from Valgrind:

```
Thread 456: status = VgTs_WaitSys
==4182==    at 0x4E383EC: recv (recv.c:34)
==4182==    by 0x4017F1: process_data (socket2.h:45)
==4182==    by 0x40195E: thread (FBServer.c:82)
==4182==    by 0x4E30A03: start_thread (pthread_create.c:300)
==4182==    by 0x532DD4C: clone (clone.S:112)

Thread 457: status = VgTs_WaitSys
==4182==    at 0x4E383EC: recv (recv.c:34)
==4182==    by 0x4017F1: process_data (socket2.h:45)
==4182==    by 0x40195E: thread (FBServer.c:82)
==4182==    by 0x4E30A03: start_thread (pthread_create.c:300)
==4182==    by 0x532DD4C: clone (clone.S:112)

...

Thread 499: status = VgTs_WaitSys
==4182==    at 0x4E383EC: recv (recv.c:34)
==4182==    by 0x4017F1: process_data (socket2.h:45)
==4182==    by 0x40195E: thread (FBServer.c:82)
==4182==    by 0x4E30A03: start_thread (pthread_create.c:300)
==4182==    by 0x532DD4C: clone (clone.S:112)
```

At line 82 in FBServer.c, the thread calls a function called process_data that receives data from the client. The function process_data is shown below:

```
void process_data(int clientSock)
{
    size_t n;
    char jstring[MAX_LEN + 1];
    int bytes_received_so_far = 0;
    int bytes_count;
    char *buf = NULL;

    while(bytes_count = recv(clientSock, jstring, MAX_LEN, 0))
    {
        if(bytes_count <= 0)
        {
            close(clientSock);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }

        printf("Bytes received = %d\n", bytes_count);                           
        jstring[bytes_count] = '\0';

        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Can someone help me in interpreting the error messages.

Comment: Is this the first error (or output at all) that valgrind gives you ?

Comment: What platform are you on?  It is platform dependent if you are being limited by number of open file descriptors.  For instance, on my Linux box I can have 1024 open files and 128 half-open connections at a time.

Comment: Not sure if this is related to your case. But in my case issue was caused by running out of threads. Increasing --max-threads might solve it (but you should also see what is causing the excessive number of threads if that is not expected).

Answer (score 2):

What version of Valgrind are you using?

About the only comment I could find in the source was:

`VgTs_WaitSys,    /* waiting for a syscall to complete */`

So it appears to indicate that the program is just blocking on a system call (recv in your case).  I'm not sure, but this may not be an error at all, just some extra info kicked out by Valgrind.

Comment: Would be consistent with the message showing up right after a recv() that blocks. In which case it's not an error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad answer, but it's too long to be a comment.

I am guessing that "VgTs_" means something like "Valgrind Threads". Valgrind serializes threads. Here's a [link to documentation](https://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.pthreads). So that means that Valgrind needs to be able to know the state of each thread.

It accomplishes this by saying "Here are the possible states": "Runnable", "Waiting on a sys call", "Yielding", etc. To prevent naming conflicts, prefix with "ValGrind Thread status".

- `VgTs_WaitSys` means that Valgrind knows it cannot run this thread until the syscall stops blocking.
- `VgTs_Runnable` means that Valgrind knows it could run the thread. But that doesn't mean that it is actively running it - as Valgrind will only run one thread at once (unless you use `DRD` or `Helgrind` as the tool, then I don't know what it does.)
- `VgTs_Yielding` I guess it's useful to be aware of this transition state.